# positioning of bootstrap button groups in grid layout

Tags: bootstrap-4

How can i get my bootstrap button group to line up in columns. My am laying out a question and multiple choice answer, i want the question and the answers to be on the same line. I am trying to have the question and all the answer fields in columns that line up together and the buttons should all stretch to the same height as other answers for that question on that line.

I have played around with various formats with rows and columns and groups with no success. When scaled down the columns look better but when in full view the button alignment is off and they dont fill the columns correctly

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>bootstrap</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form action="home.html" method="post">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-primary text-light text-center">Development</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="btn-group " role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                    <div class="text-primary col">
                        This is a question 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check active" name="devq1" value="a1" id="dq1a1" checked>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="dq1a1">No version control or used
                            infrequent</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="devq1" value="a2" id="dq1a2">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="dq1a2">Version control on all source code</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="devq1" value="a3" id="dq1a3">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="dq1a3">Version control on all source code and
                            library and artificats</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                    <div class="text-primary col">
                        This is question 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="devq2" value="b1" id="dq2a1" checked>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="dq2a1">Manual deployment process</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="devq2" value="b2" id="dq2a2">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="dq2a2">Partially automated deployment
                            process</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="devq2" value="b3" id="dq2a3"
                               autocomplete="off">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="dq2a3">Fully automated deployment process</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-primary text-light text-center">Process</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                    <div class="text-primary col">
                        This is question 3
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="processq1" value="a1" id="pq1a1" checked>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="pq1a1">Big work batch size and releases on a
                            monthly
                            basis or longer</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="processq1" value="a2" id="pq1a2">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="pq1a2">Work batch size optimized for weekly
                            releases, but deployment frequency not in sync with business requirements (e.g lead
                            time)</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="processq1" value="a3" id="pq1a3">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="pq1a3">Work batch size optimized for frequent
                            releases and deployment frequency in sync with business requirements (e.g. lead
                            time)</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                    <div class="text-primary col">
                        This is question 4
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="processq2" value="b1" id="pq2a1" checked>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="pq2a1">Change approval needed from multiple
                            parties
                            outside the team</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="processq2" value="b2" id="pq2a2">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="pq2a2">Change approval needed within the
                            team</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="processq2" value="b3" id="pq2a3">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="pq2a3">No change approval needed or change
                            approval
                            process totally automated which is really long to see what happens with the
                            buttons </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <input class="col-2 btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this using `.btn-toolbar` to align the button group and the question and ensure that the question and button group are the same height and use col to align the buttons and questions.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>bootstrap</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form action="home.html" method="post">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-primary text-light text-center">Development</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                    <div class="col-2 text-primary">This is a question 1</div>
                    <div class="btn-group col-10" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check active" name="devq1" value="a1" id="dq1a1" checked>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary col-4" for="dq1a1">No version control or used
                            infrequent</label>
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="devq1" value="a2" id="dq1a2">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary col-4" for="dq1a2">Version control on all source
                            code</label>
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="devq1" value="a3" id="dq1a3">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary col-4" for="dq1a3">Version control on all source code and
                            library and artificats</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                    <div class="col-2 text-primary">This is question 2</div>
                    <div class="btn-group col-10" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="devq2" value="b1" id="dq2a1" checked>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary col-4" for="dq2a1">Manual deployment process</label>
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="devq2" value="b2" id="dq2a2">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary col-4" for="dq2a2">Partially automated deployment
                            process</label>
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="devq2" value="b3" id="dq2a3"
                               autocomplete="off">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary col-4" for="dq2a3">Fully automated deployment
                            process</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-primary text-light text-center">Process</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                    <div class="col-2 text-primary">This is question 3</div>
                    <div class="btn-group col-10" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="processq1" value="a1" id="pq1a1" checked>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary col-4" for="pq1a1">Big work batch size and releases on a
                            monthly
                            basis or longer</label>
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="processq1" value="a2" id="pq1a2">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary col-4" for="pq1a2">Work batch size optimized for weekly
                            releases, but deployment frequency not in sync with business requirements (e.g lead
                            time)</label>
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="processq1" value="a3" id="pq1a3">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary col-4" for="pq1a3">Work batch size optimized for frequent
                            releases and deployment frequency in sync with business requirements (e.g. lead
                            time)</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                    <div class="col-2 text-primary">This is question 4</div>
                    <div class="btn-group col-10" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="processq2" value="b1" id="pq2a1" checked>
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary col-4" for="pq2a1">Change approval needed from multiple
                            parties
                            outside the team</label>
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="processq2" value="b2" id="pq2a2">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary col-4" for="pq2a2">Change approval needed within the
                            team</label>
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="processq2" value="b3" id="pq2a3">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary col-4" for="pq2a3">No change approval needed or change
                            approval
                            process totally automated which is really long to see what happens with the
                            buttons </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <input class="col-2 btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

to be honest im not very clear about what you're asking however the way i would do this is by using bootstrap `table-borderless` here is an example of what i mean :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>bootstrap</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body><div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-primary text-light text-center">Development</div>
            <div class="card-body">
<table class="table table-borderless">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
            <div class="text-primary">
                This is a question 1
            </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check active" name="devq1" value="a1" id="dq1a1" checked>
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="dq1a1">No version control or used infrequent</label>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check active" name="devq1" value="a1" id="dq1a1" >
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="dq1a1">Version control on all source code</label>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check active" name="devq1" value="a1" id="dq1a1" >
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="dq1a1">Version control on all source code and library and artificats</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
            <div class="text-primary">
                This is a question 2
            </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check active" name="devq1" value="a1" id="dq1a1" checked>
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="dq1a1">Manual deployment process</label>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check active" name="devq1" value="a1" id="dq1a1" >
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="dq1a1">Partially automated deployment process</label>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check active" name="devq1" value="a1" id="dq1a1" >
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="dq1a1">Fully automated deployment process</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
        </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So i essentially want to use a radio button group like in the bootstrap5 docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/button-group/#checkbox-and-radio-button-groups. however i want the buttons in the group to all be the same width and height regardless of the text inside them.